# Linux device-mapper & ext4: what happens when the COW table fills up?

Tags: lvm, rsnapshot

Consider the following scenario:

- I use Linux device mapper to create a snapshot of an ext4 file system.
- The snapshot is mounted as read-only; the source volume is mounted as read-write.
- I read the snapshot, and simultaneously write (too much) to the source volume. Eventually, the copy-on-write table fills up.

Now exactly what happens *in practice* from the user's perspective? What kind of messages should I expect to see in dmesg? How do the applications that read the snapshot behave? Has someone actually tried this to see what would happen?

Comment: This looks interesting, but I don't understand why you ask that instead of trying it yourself - since you know exactly how to trigger such situation.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Not that easy right now, unfortunately... Besides, I suspect that the answer is non-unique and may depend on the exact circumstances; hence I would be happy to hear of any experiences that other people have had with this kind of situations.

Comment: Did you read this Q&A: [LVM is reporting I/O errors, but the disk reports no problems. Argh](http://serverfault.com/questions/189803/lvm-is-reporting-i-o-errors-but-the-disk-reports-no-problems-argh) ?

Comment: @Mat: Thanks, this is certainly relevant; perhaps you could post it as an answer (link + a brief summary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the COW fills up, you start getting I/O errors on write operations.

LVM2 allows you to check the size and usage of the COW, and resize it if necessary.